# can't access getSystemService

Tags: android, clojure, clojure-java-interop, neko

I'm trying to call `getSystemService` (method of `Activity`) to access sensors, but looks like it doesn't exist.

Here's the code I tried:

```
(in-ns 'com....) ; Some Neko project
(.getSystemService a) ; a is :def of Activity
```

I even checked all the methods of `a` with

```
(use '[clojure.reflect :as r])
(require '[clojure.pprint :only print-table])
(print-table (:members (r/reflect a)))
```

There was `getSystemService` in a list.
But somehow I can't call it: Clojure says there's no such method.

**UPDATE:** `getSystemService` is not a static method, so that's the reason, I guess.

But still, is there a way?

Comment: I am not an Android expert, but it appears that `Activity.getSystemService()` takes a `String` parameter, for example `(.getSystemService a "window")`. At least that is what [Activity javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) says.

Comment: @ez121sl You were right, thank you! Can you post an answer? I can do it by myself, but I guess it's not fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `Activity` [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), `Activity.getSystemService()` takes a `String` argument. There is no overloaded method that takes no arguments. The message saying there is no such method means there is no method by that name that takes no arguments. Try calling `getSystemService` with a `String` argument, for example:

```
(.getSystemService a "window")
```